# Using css columns for image grid, sometimes images stack

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm using the technique described [here](https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid) and have a problem where sometimes the images arrange themselves in columns as intended, but sometimes they stack underneath each other which isn't what I want.

I tried adding `white-space:nowrap` which gets the images to display on the same line but it also removes the `column-gap` and makes the images align left instead of centred.

I've created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tyssen/pen/zQMNvb) which illustrates the problem. Set 1 stacks (bad), Set 2 is in columns (good).

Anyone have an idea why the two sets of images behave differently and a way to solve it which doesn't also sacrifice the gap and alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `float:left` to `img`

```css
.img-columns {
  column-gap: 1rem;
  column-count: 2;
  white-space: normal;
}

.img-columns img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://andersons.tyssendesign.com.au/assets/css/site.combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container mx-auto px-6">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <h1 class="px-6 mb-6">Set 1</h1>
    <div class="px-6 md:float-none md:w-full mb-4  mx-auto  text-center img-columns">
      <img class="img-content lazyloaded" src="https://andersons.tyssendesign.com.au/site/assets/files/1387/s-fold-blog-1.480x0.jpg">
      <img class="img-content  lazyloaded" src="https://andersons.tyssendesign.com.au/site/assets/files/1387/s-fold-blog-2.480x0.jpg">
    </div>

    <h1 class="px-6 mb-6">Set 2</h1>
    <div class="px-6 md:float-none md:w-full mb-4  mx-auto  text-center img-columns">
      <img class="img-content lazyloaded" src="https://andersons.tyssendesign.com.au/site/assets/files/1363/bauhaus.480x0.jpg">
      <img class="img-content lazyloaded" src="https://andersons.tyssendesign.com.au/site/assets/files/1363/matka.480x0.jpg">
      <img class="img-content lazyloaded" src="https://andersons.tyssendesign.com.au/site/assets/files/1363/yokun.480x0.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```